# Graph shows count instead of description

Tags: crystal-reports

My crystal report generates a horizontal bar graph. When I move my X-axis expression, it shows the Count instead of the Description.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: click on your field (Count of ...), then check the `Don't Summarize` Check box. It must be unchecked.

Comment: @Zeina  As i clicked on field, Don't summarize gets disable

Comment: Also i'm not using any formula field in my report

Comment: Well this is normal, since you are showing your bar horsontally, try to revert the data: place the description in the box above, and the numerical data below.

Comment: Mr. @Zeina i need description on each of the boxes. i dnt need of numerical value

Comment: Plz Show us a sample of your data and the structure to know what you are talking about.